# Adding Duplicate to variable using useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to update an object using useState by finding by id and adding a tag to it. The code below seems to be working perfectly. The ternary operator is there because originally, the tags property does not exist so it just initializes it on the first tag add.

```
let newStudents = students.map(student => {
    if(student.id === id) {
        student.tags ? student.tags.push(tag) : student.tags = [tag];
    }
    return student;
});

setStudents(newStudents);
```

However, the method below seems to be adding duplicate tags. I am using prevStudents, which I believe uses the previous state stored in the useState, then making a new object with it that has the updated tags, and finally updating students with 'return newStudents'.

```
setStudents((prevStudents) => {
    const newStudents = prevStudents.map((student) => {
        if (student.id === id) {
            student.tags ? (student.tags.push(tag)) : (student.tags = [tag]);
        }
        return student;
   });
   return newStudents;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return new object when you want to update a student state:

```
setStudents((prevStudents) => {
    const newStudents = prevStudents.map((student) => {
        if (student.id === id) {
             return {
               ...student,
               tags: student.tags ? [...student.tags, tag] : [tag]
             };
        }
        return student;
   });
   return newStudents;
});
```

I think it should work now.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working, and when I console log both studentsCopy and prevStudents they output the same thing. I guess I'll just stick to option 1, but I would have preferred to use this method as I would rather bring one variable (setStudents) down through props than 2 (students & setStudents).

Comment: I updated my answer, try it again and let me know if it works.